# In VR development ,how can I make a handle shotting?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, htc-vive

I want to make an example of shot,
then I wrote this in the handle button event，

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class fire : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject bullet;

SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;
void start() {
    trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrakedObject>();
}
void Update() {
    var device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);
    if (device.GetTouchDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger)) {
        GameObejct obj = Instantiate(bullet,transform.position);
        Vector3d fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        obj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(fwd*2800);
    }
}
}
```

but when debugging and I press handle button ,it didn't produce a bullet,and had erred at the line 
`var device = SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index);`,
the error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: trackedObj is null. Try using a capital S in your Start method. Not sure if they're case sensitive, but it seems like it.

Comment: And if that didnt work, make sure the object this script is attached to actually have the SteamVR_TrackedObject in it

Comment: ok,I use a capital S in my Strat mehod,it can work,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First You should need to confirm that your **fire** script is attached to your controller object and your controller object also attached **SteamVR_TrackedObject** script (which provide by steam plugin).
Then, lastly ensure this line is executing

```
void start() {
    trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrakedObject>();
}
```